# How to make the AmbientReverb of a roblox game change locally for a player once it has entered a area/part

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TzMc.png)

How to make this work (I didn't create the script.)
I want the game.SoundService.AmbientReverb to change from Arena to padded cell when player walks into the "Box" called workspace.Map.SoundZones.RubbleZone

```
function trip(owo)
    local noob = owo.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if owo then
        game.SoundService.AmbientReverb.Value = "Padded Cell"
    end
end

function trip2(owo)
    local noob = owo.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if not owo then
        game.SoundService.AmbientReverb.Value = "Arena"
    end
end




script.Parent.Touched:Connect(trip)
script.Parent.StoppedTouching:Connect(trip2)
```

---